# Change date format from "yyyymmdd" to "mm/dd/yyyy"

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I've tried a lot of different ways and I can't seem to get it right.

Here is the code of what I have tried so far...

```
[String]$dateValue = '20161212'
[String]$dateStamp = $dateValue -f (Get-Date)
[String]$dateStamp2 = ([datetime]::parseexact($dateValue, "yyyyMMdd", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)).Date
[String]$dateStamp3 = ([datetime]::FromFileTime($dateValue)).ToString('g')

Write-Host '$dateStamp  = ' $dateStamp
Write-Host '$dateStamp2 = ' $dateStamp2
Write-Host '$dateStamp3 = ' $dateStamp3
```

## Current Code Output

```
$dateStamp = 20161212
$dateStamp2 = 12/12/2016 00:00:00
$dateStamp3 = 12/31/1600 5:00 PM
```

## Desired Code Output

```
$dateStamp = 12/12/2016
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: `$dateStamp2` seems correct.  How do you intend to come up with 3:00 PM when that information isn't in the source string?

Comment: $dateStamp3` is totally wrong, because you're not starting with a FileTime, and therefore you can't get what you want from `FromFileTime` (which should be clear by reading the method name). Where does this imaginary time come from that you want to retrieve? You never assigned one when you initialize `$dateValue`; do you expect 3:00PM to just magically appear?

Comment: TBH, I wasn't thinking about how to handle the hh:mm. I guess the actual time doesn't matter since it's not provided, but the format should still at least be '**/**/****'. I updated the question to exclude the HH:MM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you have a datetime object it's easy to convert it to whatever string format you need. You are so close with your second attempt. Adding `ToString` allows you to specify a string format.

```
([datetime]::parseexact($dateValue, "yyyyMMdd", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Nick!

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have a culture-invariant string as your input and that you want a fixed output format, you may as well perform string parsing, without the need to convert to an intermediate `[datetime]` instance:

```
> '20161213' -replace '\d{2}(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})', '$2/$3/$1'
12/13/16
```

<sup>Note that I've changed the day to be different from the month to better highlight the reformatting that takes place.</sup>

Generally, though, the `[datetime]`-based method demonstrated in [Nick's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36562319/45375) gives you the most flexibility.

Comment: Good suggestion. However I'm not too comfortable doing regex when dealing with date comparisons, and would prefer the [datetime] library be used. But I certainly thank you for the valid thought (I never know when something like this may be useful).   :)

Comment: @FiddleFreak: My pleasure; yes, `[datetime]` is generally preferable, especially when it comes to date comparisons/calculations/culture-awareness.