# Powershell Cleanest way to convert a string to mmddyyyy format

Tags: powershell, datetime, string-formatting

Thank you in advance...

I have String output:

```
2021-12-23
```

the string Base.Type is System.Object

I would like to convert it to:

```
12-23-2021
```

or

```
12/23/2021
```

any ideas?

Comment: With my culture settings, I can do `([datetime]'2021-12-23').ToShortDateString()` or `([datetime]'2021-12-23').ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')` also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a DateTime in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249619/how-to-format-a-datetime-in-powershell)

Comment: How do you define "cleanest"?  Cleaner than what?  Splitting by the delimiter and reassembling?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change date format from "yyyymmdd" to "mm/dd/yyyy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562124/change-date-format-from-yyyymmdd-to-mm-dd-yyyy)  (Same concept of parsing and re-formatting, just substitute the applicable input - `'yyyy\-MM\-dd'` - and output - `'MM-dd-yyyy'` - date formats.)

Comment: ah perfect!  ([datetime] $year[0]).ToString('MM"/"dd"/"yyyy')   -   did the trick!  thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Note: This question is a near-duplicate of [Change date format from "yyyymmdd" to "mm/dd/yyyy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562124/change-date-format-from-yyyymmdd-to-mm-dd-yyyy); while the two are closely related, this question is more overtly focused on *both* parsing *from* a string to a date and then back *to* a string, using a different format; by contrast, the linked question has the *from* aspect covered as an incidental part of the question.</sup>

---

[Bali C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/799586/bali-c), in a comment on the question, came up with the most concise solution, which only requires a small tweak:

```
# Note the "\"-escaped separators - see below.
PS> Get-Date -Date 2021-12-23 -Format dd\-MM\-yyyy # or dd\/MM\/yyyy
23-12-2021
```

This will work with *most* cultures in effect, because format `yyyy-MM-dd` (as exemplified by your sample input string, `'2021-12-23'`) is a recognized format in all but a few cultures.

PowerShell *generally* tries to use the [*invariant* culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) in order for code to work the same across cultures, but in the case of *cmdlet arguments* actually *is* culture-sensitive, which is [a historical accident that cannot be fixed without breaking backward compatibility](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6989).

See below for a truly culture-invariant solution, which also explains why separator chars. `-` and `/` should be *escaped* for maximum robustness.

---

Since **PowerShell's casts use the [*invariant* culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture)** and **format `yyyy-MM-dd`** (as exemplified by your sample input string, `'2021-12-23'`) happens to be **a recognized format in that culture**, you can simply:

- **cast your string to `[datetime]`** to create a [`System.DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) instance
- and **then call `.ToString()` with the desired format string** to produce the desired string format, as shown in the many answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249619/how-to-format-a-datetime-in-powershell).

The following should work irrespective of the specific culture in effect:

```
PS> ([datetime] '2021-12-23').ToString('MM\-dd\-yyyy')
12-23-2021

PS> ([datetime] '2021-12-23').ToString('MM"/"dd"/"yyyy')
12/23/2021
```

Note that the separator chars. `-` and `/` are *escaped* / *quoted* so as to indicate that they're to be used *verbatim* (you're free to choose between `\`-escaping and embedded quoting).

This is necessary, because characters such as `/` are by default interpreted as *placeholders* for the *culture-appropriate* date separator, for instance, so - depending on the culture in effect (as reflected in `$PSCulture`) - they may be translated to a *different* character, such as `.`, for instance.

---

**If your original string representation were *not* recognized in the invariant culture, you can use [`System.DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ParseExact)** to parse your input string into a `[datetime]` (`System.DateTime`) instance before calling `.ToString()` as described above:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact(
  '2021-12-23', 
  'yyyy\-MM\-dd', 
  $null  # current culture
).ToString('MM"-"dd"-"yyyy')
```

The above again yields `'12-23-2021'`.

Note that, due to use of `$null`, the *current* culture is used for parsing, which has no effect in this case, however, given that the separator chars. use embedded quoting, and given that only *digits* are involved, not (culture-dependent) *names*, such as month names.

**If you do need the context of a *specific culture***, pass a `[cultureinfo]` instance ([`System.Globalization.CultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo)) instead of `$null`; e.g., to parse in the context of the French (France) culture, pass `[cultureinfo] 'fr-FR'`.